# Возможно ли сортировать массив сразу при добавлении

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка

Есть пустой массив:

```
array = []
```

Возможно ли сортировать его элементы сразу при добавлении, чтобы не вызывать sorted? То есть:

```
array.append(3)
array.append(2)
array.append(6)

# Массив, который ожидается
print(array)  # -> [2, 3, 6]
```

Comment: А вам зачем? Покажите как вы хотите пользоваться его сортированностью.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вроде бы типа данных, который будет *сразу же* после добавлении нового элемента сортировать массив, не существует - во всяком случае, в чистом Python.

Тем не менее, есть отдельная библиотека, поддерживающая сортируемые при добавлении элементов массивов/списков/словарей — [SortedContainers](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/). Думаю, что этот случай может Вам помочь.

Answer (score 4):

Можно написать функцию которая делает это

```
def sorted_append(l, x):
    if not l:
        return [x]
    for i in range(len(l)):
        if x <= l[i]:
            l.insert(i, x)
            return l
    return l + [x]

l = []
l = sorted_append(l, 3)
l = sorted_append(l, 2)
l = sorted_append(l, 6)
print(l) # [2, 3, 6]
```

Или класс

```
class sorted_list(list):
    def sorted_append(self, x):
        if not self:
            return self.append(x)
        for i in range(len(self)):
            if x <= self[i]:
                return self.insert(i, x)
        return self.append(x)

l = sorted_list()
l.sorted_append(3)
l.sorted_append(2)
l.sorted_append(6)
print(l) # [2, 3, 6]
```

Answer (score 4):

Есть еще такой стандартный модуль [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html), который поддерживает список в отсортированном порядке. Как и у функции `sort` у него есть аргумент `key`. В зависимости от поставленной задачи, может пригодиться. Пример:

```
from bisect import insort

l = []
insort(l, 3)
insort(l, 2)
insort(l, 6)
print(l)  # [2, 3, 6]
```